# How to use png embedded base64 code using dineshrabara/barcode

Tags: laravel, barcode

According to the documentation to embed a base64 image in a html blade template this should work:

```
{{ '<img src="data:image/png,' . DNS1D::getBarcodePNG("4", "C39+") . '" alt="barcode"   />' }}
```

But it doesn't work. How to use this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one fix that I achieved:

```
{{ '<img src="data:image/png;base64, ' . DNS1D::getBarcodePNG("4", "C39+") . '"/>' }}
```